# Deleting files from multiple subdirectories, but leaving 3 newest files in each of the subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to clean up some space and want to remove all but 3 newest files that are older than 30 days in each sub-directory of a given directory.

I was thinking to use the following script to check it's workability before I actually remove files, but for whatever reason it doesn't write anything into the output.

```
for dir in $(find /home/usr/dir/ -type d)
do
    find $dir -type f -mtime +30 - printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort-r " tail -n+4 > output.txt
done
```

I'm kind of new to the scripting so, appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: `for` loop needs to be closed with `done`, there is an extra space in `- printf`, there is a missing space in `sort-r`, there is `"` instead of `|` before `tail`.

Comment: Run you script with bash -x for see where the script is going wrong.

Comment: `it doesn't write anything into the output.` - how were you able to run it? Didn't you get any error messages?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: No it did not return any errors, which really put me off. that's basically a reason I'm asking the question. I really do appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you were close! Try something like this:

```
find /home/usr/dir/ -mindepth 1 -type d | 
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    find "$dir" -type f -mtime +30 -printf "%T+\t%p\n" |
    sort -r -k1 | tail -n +4 |
    cut -f2- |
    xargs -d $'\n' echo rm
done
```

Let's do:

- add `-mindepth 1` to the first `find`. We don't want to remove files from the `/home/usr/dir` directory itself - only from subdirectories.
- The `for i in $(find)` is very unsafe - the result of `$(find)` undergoes word splitting... It's better to use `while read` loop. More about it could be find for example at [bashfaq How to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- `-k1` I tell `sort` to sort on the first field... I'm usually pedantic. I would also use `-s -k1,1`, because we don't need to sort on the second column, less work for `sort`.
- `cut -f2-` - Let's remove the timestamps and leave only files.
- `xargs -d $'\n' echo rm` - `xargs` takes each line from input and appends it as an argument to the command `echo rm`. Remove the `echo` to really remove the files. You can add `-t` to `xargs` to see what it is executing and `-v` to `rm` to see which files are getting removed.
- The list after `tail -n+4` may be empty - if so, `xargs` will run the command with no arguments and I guess `rm` will fail with `rm: missing operand` massage. If so, you need to save the result to some temp variable, check if it's empty, if it's not remove the files like `var=$(find .... | cut); if [ -n "$var" ]; then <<<"$var" xargs -d $'\n' echo rm; fi`. The GNU xargs has `-r, --no-run-if-empty` option.